# Syncronization of Timestamps

Tags: ros, syncronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Currently I am logging the IMU data , GPS data and other data but since these nodes log data at different frequencies , my post processing is pointless ( Timestamps are different ). I need to find out a way by which I can synchronize all the data so I can do my post processing.

Thank you in advance,
Naz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189338/syncronization-of-timestamps/) by [Naz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19964/naz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
Are you using this data for robot_pose_ekf?

**Comment by [Naz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19964/naz/) on 2014-08-07**:
I am using this data for my research on Cooperative Navigation.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
robot_pose_ekf is a filtering node for more accurate position. Didnt mean for what project are you using it for. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the ExactTime and ApproximateTime Synchronization methods in ROS.

http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime

http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

In the answer at the link below, there is a sample code that subscribes to two point clouds and uses ApproximateTime policy for synchronization.

http://answers.ros.org/question/186281/problem-using-callback-with-multiple-arguments-via-approximatetime-synchronizer/

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2